# getting N number from user and find the biggest

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm writing my first code in c++.
I want recieve in N number from user and find the biggest one.
I just have learnt itteration,if statement...(no list)
Please give me some guidance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to learn C++, I suggest you directly start using the standard library (stl), its containers (such as `std::vector`) and its algorithm (in this case `std::max_element`).

A range based loop is not as good as a proper algorithm, but still better than a hand crafted index based loop.

Please refer to the Book "A tour of C++" by Stroustrup. He summarizes how C++ is meant to be used now.

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr;
    const int N = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        int value;
        std::cin >> value;
        arr.push_back(value);
    }

    const auto max_algorithm = std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::cout << "Largest is: " << *max_algorithm << std::endl;    


    auto max_range_based_loop = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();
    for (const auto& item : arr) {
        max_range_based_loop = std::max(item, max_range_based_loop );
    }
    std::cout << "Largest is: " << max_range_based_loop << std::endl;
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Few remember to initialize to min for type when finding max -- that's worth the nod.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin :-) This is why the algorithm should be preferred.

Comment: Amen to that. I wonder based on the question if adding a standard iterator `(std::vector<int>::iterator iter = arr.begin(); iter != arr.end(); iter++)` may also be what the OP is after. Both the `max_element` and range-based `for` would be preferable, but the wording of the question may indicate neither have been reached yet -- I agree -- no time like the present... but something to consider as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Since the OP asked for a C++14 solution I would not post the iterator based loop in the answer. The comment section is for sure a good place to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize int max = INT_MIN.

While taking user input in an array, check if each input element is greater than `max`,
If greater, update max value.
when loop terminates return `max`.

Example:

```
int main()
{

int N = 10;  // N is array size
int arr[N]; // Array declaration 
int max = INT_MIN;

for(int i=0; i<N; i++) 
{
    cin>>arr[i];    // user input
    if(arr[i]>max)  //check each element if it's greater than max
    {
        max = arr[i];
        }   
}
cout<<"Largest is: "<<max<<endl; // print max Or return it in a method
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question about c++14 and the answer is a raw array. Made me laugh

Comment: @Thrasher Algorithm would be same i guess, no? convert it into C++14 or do it using stl

Comment: int is signed, 0 may be the max with your code if inputs are negative.

Comment: @Mansoor yes when other elements are negatives. in that case max = INT_MIN updated! Thanks!